# ical create event ios

Tags: ios, calendar, icalendar, reminders

I have successfully subscribe to my iCal calendar and I can view events and it is updated. However I am unable to create alarms or reminders if I view an individual event. Normally there is an edit button for any calendar event that is loaded from my normal calendar which is on exchange.

I thought I heard somewhere you may have to use web dav server to do reminders or alarms for one particular event. Is this true or has anyone had any luck getting to reminders to work.

Below is what php generates as the ics file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//My/Calendar//NONSGML v1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:My Calendar
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Chicago
X-WR-CALDESC:Calendar Events
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1M
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Chicago
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/Chicago
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0600
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:CDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0600
DTSTART:19701025T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20110119T123850
DTSTAMP:20130211T031208Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20120209
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20120209
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:
 To edit this event, go to: https://mywebsite.com/events/edit/15
SUMMARY:My B-day
UID:4efbf8ee376152344030ede518327cbaf4c41b5f
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
```

Thanks,
Bart

Comment: It doesn't sound like a programming question. Perhaps [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) is a better place to ask?

Comment: Ok, however I can post the code I use to generate the iCal, if that helps...

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're doing it programatically, I thought you were using an app.

Comment: No problem it is a rather vague question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit your events you need to have a CalDAV server serving your iCalendar file.  Right now you are just serving a read-only iCalendar file so your calendar application has no way of editing it.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean even editing a ics file locally on an iphone can only be done with CalDav server?